# setGeometry obstructed by setText

Tags: c++, qt, slider, resize, window-resize

I created a Qt Widget in Qt Creator which consists of a QSlider and a QProgressBar whose length I want to adjust to the position of the slider like this:
[image]
To do so, I use `setGeometry()`. In order to maintain the length relative to the window width, I call my `resizeProgressBar()` in my overridden `resizeEvent()`. The slider's value is also shown in the label below the progress bar. However, the `setText()` call in `on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged()` seems to interfere with the `setGeometry()`, as only when I resize the window, the progress bar assumes the desired length, but each time I move the slider, the progress bar reverts to spanning the full width of the window. It does not matter whether the `setText()` comes before or after the `setGeometry()`.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::resizeProgressBar()
{
    ui->progressBar->setGeometry(ui->progressBar->x(), ui->progressBar->y(),
                                 ui->horizontalSlider->width()
                                         * ui->horizontalSlider->value()
                                         / ui->horizontalSlider->maximum(),
                                 ui->progressBar->height());
}

void MainWindow::on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged(int value)
{
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(ui->horizontalSlider->value()));
    resizeProgressBar();
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    resizeProgressBar();
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(ui->horizontalSlider->value()));
    QWidget::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the originally intended way did not work, I've now solved the problem by using a horizontal layout containing the QProgressBar as well as a horizontal Spacer on the right of the bar. The stretch factors are set to 1 and 0, respectively. Now, when I move the slider, I change the stretch factors accordingly, so the progress bar is aligned with the slider's value.

```
void MainWindow::on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged(int value)
{
    ui->horizontalLayout->setStretch(0, value);
    ui->horizontalLayout->setStretch(1, ui->horizontalSlider->maximum() - value);
}
```